# Fetching single records using Redux Crud?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I've been using [redux-crud](https://github.com/Versent/redux-crud), and really like it. I'm still very new to Redux itself, so the following question may seem a bit noob.

I'm at the point where I want to fetch just a single record freshly from the server when I enter the edit form for it. I can't rely on the record that might have been previously fetched into the state, to be the most accurate representation of it for editing purposes.

Based on my current understanding, it doesn't seem that `redux-form` is suited to fetching singles, rather it seems to suggest that I pull the record for edit out of the collection of records already in the state (previously fetched with the out of the box crud actions and reducers).

I have a type of record called `Providers`.

Am I right to say that I'm going to have to create a separate set of fetch actions and reducers that are suited to singular fetching?

So where Redux Crud would give me `PROVIDERS_FETCH_SUCCESS`, I would then need to go on and implement `PROVIDER_FETCH_SUCCESS` in a singular fashion? Or is there a simpler way out of the box with Redux Crud that I'm not seeing clearly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

redux-crud will manage updating items for you when you need to fetch individual entities.  `actionCreatorsFor` and `reducersFor` both take optional secondary arguments to specify what

```
reduxCrud.actionCreatorsFor('providers', {key: '_id'});
reduxCrud.Map.reducersFor('providers', {key: '_id'});
```

You can then mark the action as "replace" to replace existing items that have matching key fields;

```
fetchSuccess(providers, {replace: true});
```

Or

```
fetchSuccess([provider], {replace: true});
```